# Why React native app frozen in splash screen on release build, works fine on debug?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo

I have an expo app with bare workflow. While everything is fine in debug mode, my application in production mode that I created with the "expo build:android" command freezes on the splash screen.

adb logcat '*:E' log's at the here: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-forest-7k5ezc?file=/src/index.js:0-548918 (I added it here because of the character limit.)

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "test",
    "slug": "test",
    "scheme": "test",
    "version": "1.0.3",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/playstore.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash/example.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#213348",
      "resizeMode": "contain"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "requireFullScreen": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.xxx.app"
    },
    "android": {
      "permissions": [
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "CAMERA",
        "FOREGROUND_SERVICE",
        "INTERNET",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "RECORD_AUDIO",
        "SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW",
        "VIBRATE",
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "WRITE_SETTINGS"
      ],
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/playstore.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "splash": {
        "backgroundColor": "#213348",
        "resizeMode": "contain",
        "mdpi": "./assets/splash/example.png",
        "hdpi": "./assets/splash/example_x1.5.png",
        "xhdpi": "./assets/splash/example_x2.png",
        "xxhdpi": "./assets/splash/example_x3.png",
        "xxxhdpi": "./assets/splash/example_x4.png"
      },
      "package": "com.xxx.app",
      "versionCode": 4
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps",
      "expo-facebook",
      ["expo-location", { "isAndroidBackgroundLocationEnabled": false }]
    ]
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** If I leave alerts on uploading like this they don't work because it doesn't even render App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import MainNavigator from "./navigator/MainNavigator";
import { StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { persistor, store } from "./store/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { permissionHandler, useFonts } from "./helper/helper";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { NotifierWrapper } from "react-native-notifier";

function App() {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  const loadFonts = async () => {
    Alert.alert("Test", "example description", [
      {
        text: "Yes",
      },
      {
        text: "No",
      },
    ]);
    await useFonts();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isReady) {
      StatusBar.setBarStyle("light-content", true);
    }
  }, [isReady]);

  const setReady = async () => {
    Alert.alert("Test", "example description", [
      {
        text: "Yes",
      },
      {
        text: "No",
      },
    ]);
    await permissionHandler();
    openApp();
  };

  const openApp = () => setIsReady(true);

  if (!isReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={loadFonts}
        onFinish={setReady}
        onError={(error) => console.error(error)}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <NotifierWrapper>
            <MainNavigator />
          </NotifierWrapper>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "examplename",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/configure-splash-screen": "^0.6.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "7.1.3",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.1.12",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^7.0.4",
    "@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps": "^8.5.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^3.3.3",
    "@use-expo/screen-orientation": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "expo": "^44.0.6",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~4.1.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.4.5",
    "expo-auth-session": "~3.5.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~11.2.0",
    "expo-battery": "~6.1.0",
    "expo-brightness": "^10.1.1",
    "expo-camera": "~12.0.3",
    "expo-face-detector": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-facebook": "~12.1.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.4",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-keep-awake": "~10.0.1",
    "expo-location": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-network": "~4.1.0",
    "expo-random": "~12.1.1",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~4.1.1",
    "expo-sensors": "~11.1.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-sqlite": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "expo-task-manager": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.11.6",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "ios-deploy": "^1.11.4",
    "jsog": "^1.0.7",
    "md5": "^2.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.3.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-notifier": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^4.3.7",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.1",
    "react-native-popover-view": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-switch-selector": "^2.1.4",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-native-zip-archive": "^6.0.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "rn-sliding-up-panel": "^2.4.5",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Did u get the solution ?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.